# Poison distribution question Stats

Tags: poisson-distribution

A busy railway station has two taxi stands at separate exits, A and B.
At stand A, taxis arrive according to a Poisson Process of rate 2 per minute.

Assume that any arriving train passenger who requires a taxi goes to stand A with
probability 0.7 or to stand B with probability 0.3. At stand B, taxis arrive according
to a Poisson Process of rate 1 per minute.

Three minutes after reaching the front of the queue at one of the taxi stands, a
train passenger finds herself still waiting for a taxi. Given this information, find
the probability that this passenger is waiting at taxi stand A.

---

I've spent some time thinking about this question, though nothing much really comes to mind.

Part of me believes I should use all the information given, however I'm having a hard time linking the given information to what we need to find.

Some suggestions would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

Let $T$ be the event that you wait for more than $3$ minutes
\begin{align}
P(A|T) = \frac{p(A)P(T|A)}{P(T)}
\end{align}